# Error in assigning values to raster in R

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-raster

I'm trying to follow the code to construct a residual autocovariate model described here: https://github.com/jejoenje/PubsRexamples/blob/master/Crase_etal.R#L16

After creating a large raster space I get an error when assigning values to the raster. I have 1000 random points to sign to the raster so there are many points without data (NA). Any ideas?

```
head(xy)
         [,1]    [,2]
[1,] 543510.0 6968620
[2,] 543570.0 6968620
[3,] 543570.0 6968560
[4,] 543599.9 6968560
[5,] 543510.0 6968530
[6,] 543389.9 6968470


head(xy_residuals)
      [,1]    [,2]       [,3]
1 543510.0 6968620 -0.4257671
2 543570.0 6968620 -0.4541684
3 543570.0 6968560 -0.4310492
4 543599.9 6968560 -0.4649595
5 543510.0 6968530 -0.5506348
6 543389.9 6968470 -0.4928708

summary(xy)
           X               Y   
Min.   :538800   Min.   :6931480  
1st Qu.:540480   1st Qu.:6932860  
Median :541350   Median :6935320  
Mean   :541529   Mean   :6943218  
3rd Qu.:542670   3rd Qu.:6954003  
Max.   :544290   Max.   :6968620  

# Define raster ymn, ymx, xmn and xmx from coordinates 
# ncol=xmx-xmn nrow=ymx-ymn.

rast <- raster(ncol = 5490, nrow = 37140, ymn = 6931480, ymx = 6968620, 
               xmn = 538800, xmx = 544290)
rast

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 37140, 5490, 203898600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 1, 1  (x, y)
extent      : 538800, 544290, 6931480, 6968620  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA
```

Problematic call:

```
rast[cellFromXY(rast, xy)] <- xy_residuals[, 3]
```

> Error in .replace(x, i = i, value = value, recycle = 1) : 
>       cannot replace values in large Raster objects if their length is not      1 or the number of cells to be replaced**

Comment: Do lengths of `cellFromXY(rast, xy)` and `xy_residuals[, 3]` match?

Comment: Yes.  Both xy and xy_residuals have 1000 rows

Comment: I'm out of ideas. At this point it would be great if you could provide a reproducible example (which is easy to copy/paste).

Answer (score 2):

The error message says why this happens (But perhaps this "feature" needs some improvement.) The raster is very large and may not fit in memory (RAM). That may be too conservative an assessment . You can adjust that via `rasterOptions` or you can try:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10, ymn = 6931480, ymx = 6968620, xmn = 538800, xmx = 544290)
m <- matrix(c(539868,542002,542409,6945031,6940012,6935997, 1, 2, 3), 3, 3)    
cells <- cellFromXY(r, m[,1:2])

# create a large vector with all cells
v <- rep(NA, ncell(r))
v[cells] <- m[,3]
v <- setValues(r, v)
```

If that does not work, you could look at `update`, but that is more risky as it overwrites data on file, but that should not be a concern in this case.

```
r <- setValues(r, NA)
# that probably creates a file on disk. If not do
# r <- writeRaster(r, filename='test.grd')

r <- update(r, cell=cells, v=m[,3])
```

Comment: Thanks I found this very helpful with a similar problem